# U4091 Reason 00000006

Tags: c, posix, mainframe, zos

What does an abend U4091 reason 00000006 mean?

[IBM Docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=codes-u4091-xffb) have this to say:

> **X'06' (6)** A request to resume the application was not accepted. The Language Environment condition manager does not accept resumption
> requests with conditions, such as abends.

I do not know what that means - what is a resumption request?

I get this at shutdown of my program, everything seems to have shutdown successfully. Nothing is failing, except this abend. I assume it is some part of LE that is complaining. The name of the active module in the abend is CELQLIB.

The job shows this:-

```
+CEE3797I LANGUAGE ENVIRONMENT HAS DYNAMICALLY CREATED A DUMP.       
IEA995I SYMPTOM DUMP OUTPUT  651                                     
  USER COMPLETION CODE=4091 REASON CODE=00000006                     
 TIME=04.06.18  SEQ=00110  CPU=0000  ASID=0022                       
 PSW AT TIME OF ERROR  078D1401   B45AECCA  ILC 2  INTC 0D           
   ACTIVE MODULE           ADDRESS=00000000_340F1000  OFFSET=004BDCCA
   NAME=CELQLIB                                                      
   DATA AT PSW  345AECC4 - 00181610  0A0DEBEC  4A4C0096              
   GR 0: 00000000_84000000   1: 00000000_84000FFB                    
      2: 00000000_00000006   3: 00000050_00103E28                    
      4: 00000050_423FD3A0   5: 00000000_345AECD8                    
      6: 00000050_423FDEA8   7: 00000050_423FE0D8                    
      8: 00000000_00000000   9: 00000000_00000001                    
      A: 00000050_423FE39F   B: 00000000_345AEDD4                    
      C: 00000050_425FEC60   D: 00000050_423FEC60                    
      E: 00000000_345AE9F2   F: 00000000_00000006                    
 END OF SYMPTOM DUMP                                                 
BPXP018I THREAD 3475800000000008, IN PROCESS 83886429, ENDED  652    
WITHOUT BEING UNDUBBED WITH COMPLETION CODE 84000FFB                 
, AND REASON CODE 00000006.
```

and wrote an MVS dump, but not a CEEDUMP.

Running the dump though IPCS with VERBX LEDATA 'CEEDUMP' shows the traceback to be:-

```
Traceback:                                                         
  DSA      Entry       E  Offset  Statement   Load Mod             Program Unit                   Service  Status
                                                                   
  1        CEEOSIGG    +00002D6A              CELQLIB              CEEOSIGG                       HLE77D0  Call
  2        CELQHROD    +00000266              CELQLIB              CELQHROD                       HLE77D0  Call
  3        MainProcess +00000000              CSQBLB16             
  4        CSQBMCSY    +00000C9C              CSQBLB16             
  5        CELQPCMM    +00000F68              CELQLIB              CELQPCMM                       HLE77D0  Call
```

None of which is my code, so perhaps it is not my problem to solve.

Comment: What does that question have to do with C? Are you even doing any programming? In any case, what did you do to get that message?

Comment: Hi @UlrichEckhardt - My program is written in C. I don't know what I did. LE spat it out when my program ended normally, gracefully. I don't even know where to start looking. I can't really post the entire source code my program. If there are many difference possibilities for this particular abend code, then I can update my question with more details, but I don't know what those details would be. If someone could just start off by telling me what a resumption request is, that would be a great start. Do you know?

Comment: This appears to have something to do with LE condition handling.  LE condition handling can be invoked by some standard C functions, see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=handlers-handling-signals-using-zos-unix-posixon.

Comment: Can you provide a sample that is an minimal version to recreate teh issue?   In addition, there should be a CEE dump provided to provide more context.   With your information it is mere speculation on how to proceed.

Comment: @Hogstrom - I would love to provide a minimal version to recreate, but since I literally have no idea what is causing it, that's a bit hard :-) I was hoping for some people to speculate and give me some ideas - or even at the very least tell me what a resumption request was since that phrase means nothing to me.

Comment: @Hogstrom - It wrote an MVS dump - presumably I could get a CEEDUMP style call stack from that in IPCS?

Comment: @Hogstrom - OK found the CEEDUMP in the MVS dump - updated question.

Comment: The dump is helpful but not definitive.  In essence you are experiencing an error and LE is attmpting to manage the error.  It appears that somewhere in LE land a module tried to resume but it was not possible and so you got the U4091.   Are there other messsages in the job log or syslog before the abend?   Also, is this in USS or a batch job?

Comment: @Hogstrom - what does "tried to resume" mean? This is batch. No other messages before the abend.

Comment: Can you put some diagnostic messages in your program to narrow down the part of your program causing the problem?

Comment: @SteveIves - I have done some narrowing and hope the next time I have free z/OS time to create a small sample that has the same behaviour, but unsure yet whether it will do so.  I have also convinced myself that it is not my code, but a library I am calling, so hoping that once I get a smallest possible sample to recreate I can let the owners of that library know and get a fix. I am hampered a little by my time and time on z/OS machines. C'est la vie. I will come back to this question when I know more.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite usual that this abend is caused by a small region for the user executing the program. Try to increase the region assigned to the user for the omvs segment.

Also check your pointers as the modules involved are sometimes involved in bad pointers.

Comment: Interesting. I did try increasing the region on the batch job. You have mentioned increasing the OMVS segment - that's not the same I guess? Interesting that it needs a bigger region only at shutdown but not for the entirety of the life of the program though! I'm curious which modules are sometimes involved in bad pointers? Again, it leaves all my code successfully with no complaints and abends only as the process ends. So not my pointers I guess.

Comment: Tha question is that this reminds me a problem when this abend occurs at end of a task. 
[PH34338](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PH34338) In this case it’s something that happened in the J9 closing. But the modules called are very similar.